# Array with null elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

My code receives several url from a request, I wish to insert each in an array and then forward to another part of code that depends on this url array (*contatosSalvos.promise.then....*)
 The element that I'm inserting **is valid and exists**, I don't get any errors. 
But when I get my URL array it comes with null values​​. My URL array is *contatosUri*. Can anyone help me why this happens?

```
 deferred.promise.then(function (resolve){
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.contatos.length; i++){
          $scope.contatos[i].agencia = resolve[i].data._links.self.href;
          salvarContatos.push(contatosAPI.postContato($scope.contatos[i]));
        }
        $q.all(salvarContatos).then(function (values){
          var i = 0;
          while(i < values.length){
            contatosUri.push(values[i].data._links.self_href);
            i++;
            if(i == values.length){
              contatosSalvos.resolve(contatosUri);
            }
          }
        }).catch(function (error){
          alert("Opsss\nOcorreu um erro ao salvar os contatos");
          console.log("Erro ao salvar contatos" + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
      });
```

Comment: Can you add logging the `values` variable within `$q.all(salvarContatos).then(function` callback?

Comment: I see `self.href` and `self_href`, can't be both, one or the other

Comment: @raina77ow: Rather than logging, how 'bout *debugging*?

Comment: Yep, most probably a typo.

Comment: If not a typo, [odds are it's this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but in something you haven't shown.

Comment: @WhiteHat I can't believe that was my problem. Thanks lol